# creating a dataframe out of multiple variables containing lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm working with the following three variables:

columns =   ['ticker', 'avg range', 'std of range', '0.5 std range', 'median range', 'highest range', 'lowest range']

After creating a variable containing the title for 7 columns, i hava two lists with 7 items to equal the amount of columns that are created.

eu_5dstats   =   [stats_list("EUR_USD","D",5)]
gu_5dstats    =   [stats_list("GBP_USD","D",5)]

I would like to create a table with two rows, which fills each column with the items in the eu_5dstats  and  gu_5dstats variables.

when i try **eutable = pd.DataFrame(eu_5dstats,columns=[columns])** this works fine, and gives me the following table.

However when I try to add more rows by adding the other list by using **table = pd.DataFrame([eu_5dstats, gu_5dstats], columns=[columns])** i get the following:

[Screenshot of my code's current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNNxy.png)

when i try table = pd.DataFrame(zip(eu_5dstats, gu_5dstats), columns=[columns]) i get a** ValueError: 7 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns**.

I would like a table with 2 rows. The first row will be the list from eu_5dstats variable, and the second row with values from the gu_5dstats variable. Like this:

[Screenshot of the result I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLCmW.png)

can someone please propose an alternative solution?

Many thanks

Comment: Add two lists: `table = pd.DataFrame(eu_5dstats + gu_5dstats, columns=[columns])`?

Comment: Oh waow, that was quite simple. Still new to coding and python :)/

Thank you that was very helpful!